# ASN.1 How to use CHOICE type

Tags: asn.1

I designed my schema like below.

```
Motorcar ::= SEQUENCE {
    carRegNumber VisibleString
}

Bicycle ::= SEQUENCE {
   bicycleColor VisibleString,
   bicycleModel VisibleString
}

Boat ::= SEQUENCE {
    boatRegNumber VisibleString
}

PreferredVehicle ::= CHOICE { car Motorcar, bicycle Bicycle, boat Boat }

Person ::= SEQUENCE {
    name VisibleString,
    id VisibleString,
    preferredVehicle PreferredVehicle
}
```

When I compiled the schema at 'http://asn1-playground.oss.com/', it is compiled successfully.

But when I created an object of type Person, I am getting errors.

```
myBicycle Bicycle ::= {
    bicycleColor "Blue",
    bicycleModel "Hero 42M"
}

person Person ::= {
    name "Rama Krishna",
    id "I123456",
    preferredVehicle myBicycle
}
```

Can any one tell me what is wrong with my schema and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that utility lets you use named subvalues. At any rate, this value seems to work fine:

```
person Person ::= {
    name "Rama Krishna",
    id "I123456",
    preferredVehicle bicycle: {
        bicycleColor "Blue",
        bicycleModel "Hero 42M"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the component of the CHOICE in your value notation.

The following should work:

```
myBicycle Bicycle ::= {
    bicycleColor "Blue",
    bicycleModel "Hero 42M"
}

person Person ::= {
    name "Rama Krishna",
    id "I123456",
    preferredVehicle bicycle : myBicycle
}
```